# Using Leaflet.js how do I get map lat/lon on drag end?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am using the leaflet.js and integrate it with my code very easily . I am unable to find the co-ordinates on drag end event like in google map . So please can anyone suggest how to do that . Any kind of help and suggestion is appreciated.

```
var map = L.map('map', {center: latlng, zoom: 13, layers: [tiles]});

var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({ chunkedLoading: true });

showData(map,markers);

map.on('dragend',function(e){
  console.log("console.log", e);
  console.log(e.target.latLngToContainerPoint);
  //showData(map,markers,e.target._animateToCenter.lat, e.target._animateToCenter.lng , e.distance)
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not just get the map center on drag end?

```
map.on('dragend',function(e){
  console.log(map.getCenter());
});
```

See example http://codepen.io/sphvn/pen/GJbxBw?editors=001

If this isn't what you are after can you please clarify your question.

Comment: Yeah Thanks Sphvn for you reply , yes I tried this and get the Map center .

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can actually get coordinates, not map center:

```js
    map.on('dragend',function(e){
        console.log(e.target._latlng);
    });
```